# What characters are "fictional characters" in Re:Creators based on

Tags: re-creators

In the show Re:Creators, fictional characters start roaming "real world". Those fictional characters where created for the show, but are often reminiscent of characters from other fictional works in reality.

What characters or combination of would be closest to the fictional characters in Re:Creators?

Comment: The question in your title ("what are they based on") is fine, assuming you're looking for a word-of-god answer (though you'll probably never get one). But the question in the body of your post ("what characters are they closest to") is very broad and opinion-based. I recommend revising your post accordingly.

Comment: @senshin I'm sure there is no world of god for this and that there are not exact characters that would fit. Most of them are either combination or based on general tropes in a genre. Vote to close as opinion based if you wish.

Comment: Right - for example, Mamika is basically a pastiche of every "classic" magical girl. What kind of answer would you want for her? There's no objective metric by which we can say "Mamika is more like Sailor Moon than she is like Kinomoto Sakura". I don't see a way for this question to get answers that are anything other than "well, my opinion is that Mamika is most like character X". I'm going to close this as opinion-based, but of course if you'd like to edit it to tighten it up, that'll kick the question into the reopen queue.

Comment: @senshin Edit it yourself if you believe it can be worded in a way that won't make it opinion-based. As I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I disagree that it is only opinion based. For instance, I came up with the same idea that Mamika was based on Madoka (Mamika's appearance during battle looks almost exactly like Madoka during the fight against Walpurgis). I don't think that there is a problem with question but rather answers should be supported with sources/references and/or proofs strong enough.

Comment: Some thoughts can be found on wiki page (Which I agree with. Especially about Alicetaria and Selesia): http://recreators.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters
I'm still curious from what RPG game Meteora came from (I guess something like Gothic or Elder Scrolls but I don't know these games so well)

Answer (score -3):

there's my opnion:

```
Kirameki, Mamika >>based on Kaname, Madoka from Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica
```

[image]

Kanoya, Rui>>>> based on  Ikari, Shinji from Neon Genesis Evangelion
[image]

```
Talker, Blitz >>>> based on Half-life main caracter.
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Fix formatting of your answer and include all other characters.